# Why are $\pi$ and $e$ simply referred to as "pi" and "e"?

Tags: notation, math-history

I'm aware of the names "Archimedes' constant" and "Euler's number" for $\pi$ and $e$ respectively, but these don't seem to be used very commonly. Even in school I remember $\pi$ and $e$ being almost always referred to as "pi" and "e", to the extent that some math students don't even understand what "Archimedes' constant" is despite using it every day.

By contrast, nearly all other mathematical concepts have descriptive names not associated with the symbols used to represent them. Think of the golden ratio $\varphi$, the imagimary unit $i$, Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, etc.

Are there any specific historical reasons why $\pi$ and $e$ are not named any better than the symbols used for them?

I asked myself this question after reading [this joke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3500). If the problem had been instead "Give an example of a transcendental number", then both "pi" and "e" would have been great answers.

Comment: [$\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Adoption_of_the_symbol_.CF.80), [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History)

Comment: Maybe this question should be referred to a linguistic?

Comment: @Ranc what does this have to do with linguistics?

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the fact that $\pi$ and $e$ are so widely used - if one says $\pi$, everyone knows you're talking about the ratio between the diameter and the circumference of a circle. However, constants like $\gamma$ or $i$ are also used in other instances - $\gamma$ being a common name for an angle (if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are used already) and $i$ is used a lot in number theory, specifically in summations. Thus, for those it is useful to give them an extra name to be sure people understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Can you imagine saying "Archimedes' constant" every time you mean $\pi$ when walking a class through a derivation?

Comment: The letter π is a perfectly good name, since it is the first letter of the Greek word περίμετρος (perimeter). As to e, it is the initial letter of both Euler and exponent.

Comment: *some math students don't even understand what “Archimedes' constant” is, despite using it every day.* - So what ? You yourself have no idea what [Legendre's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_constant) is, despite using it every day.

Comment: Both numbers are extraordinary and constantly used, so everybody knows them.

Comment: @addy2012 It falls under the category of "Why do people talk the way they talk" This has alot to do with linguistics, and study of human language. The fact that these are part of scientific terminiology is not essential to answering your question.

Comment: @Ranc This has only to do something with history, in particular with history of math.

Comment: @addy2012 I dont agree with you fully. Still i suggest you to ask a linguistic. I think he might provide you a reasonable explanation which is, in a way, independent of the history of the terms $e,\pi$.

Comment: @addy2012 It is odd stating "This has only to do something with history".
Maybe history has something to do with linguistics and philosophy of language?